# How do I go back to a prompt in the sqlite3 shell?

Tags: shell, sqlite, command-prompt, prompt

I am stuck with sqlite3 where after pressing ctrl-c on my mac a few times my prompt says:

[Process completed]

Secondly, I found that despite ctrl-c being an exit character, it doesn't do anything in my sqlite3 shell except for displaying "^C" on the prompt. Also, unlike my terminal, the down key doesn't display a history of past commands but just creates a long SQL statement of "^D"

And I have no idea how to get back to my prompt after [Process Completed]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck in SQLite's command line interface a way to return to your shell's or cmd.exe's  prompt is to type the keys Ctrl and D together losing what you did not save.

Answer (score 0):

`[Process Completed]` is Terminal.app telling you that the shell/process in that terminal window finished and there is nothing there anymore. You need to start a new terminal window.